# Android AlertDialog ReOpen or Block Close

Tags: android

I have an AlertDialog with two callback function. When the user is click to "Yes" or "No" than the callback is calling.

```
 public AlertDialog getMydialog(final Context context, final MyCallback onSuccess,final MyCallback onCancel) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("MSG");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("TITLE");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                onSuccess.callback();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                onCancel.callback();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
```

My Callbacks:

```
myDialog = new MyClass(this).MyDialog(this, new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback() {
            Log.d("test","test Click-YES");
        }
    }, new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback() {
            Log.d("test","test Click-NO");
        }
    });
myDialog.show();
```

When i Click the NO than the dialog is dismissed.
But can't show again. For example:

```
myDialog = new MyClass(this).MyDialog(this, new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback() {
            Log.d("test","test Click-YES");
        }
    }, new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback() {
            Log.d("test","test Click-NO");
            myDialog.show() // isnt work
        }
    });
myDialog.show();
```

Anyone have idea to Disable .dismiss when I click to "NO" button?
Or Reopen the dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the `Dialog` to get Dismiss you can use `setOnShowListener` on the `AlertDialog` and add your code..

```
final AlertDialog mAlertDialog = getMydialog();  //get Dialog
mAlertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        Button button = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //your code
               //you can call dissmiss later 
            }
        });

        Button button2 = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //your code
               //you can call dissmiss later 
            }
        });
    }
});
mAlertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you. It's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        .setEnabled(false);

Set this property to your alert dialog. This will disable negative button

Comment: A button without any function :| Its funny :) Maybe its so useless.